# How to change the mode of the CodeMirror editor based on selected value in SelectList

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

In my application I have a text area for text and a select list with languages that Code mirror supports. 
Can someone tell me how to change the mode (programming language) of the code mirror editor when the user selects a language from the select list? Do I need to load js files for the selected mode manually? Is there any setup needed to change that on the fly? Do I need to preload js files for all supported  modes? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [loadmode](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addon_loadmode) addon that can help with that. See the [demo](http://codemirror.net/demo/loadmode.html) for an example.

Comment: I got CodeMirror off of NPM but it did not come with loadmode

Comment: I absolutely does, you just have to make sure you actually load the addon I linked.

Comment: Yes, the documentation is somewhat inaccurate as it says meta.js is in the mode folder, which it is, but loadmode.js is in the addon/mode/loadmode.js even though they both say they're in the mode folder

Answer (score 1):

Doing it in such way:

```
function loadModeForSelectedOption() {
    var script = $("#mode option:selected").attr('data-script');
    var mode = $("#mode option:selected").attr('data-mime-type');
    loadJS(script, function () {
        myCodeMirror.setOption("mode", mode);
    });
}

function loadJS(src, callback) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = src;
    s.async = true;
    s.onreadystatechange = s.onload = function () {
        var state = s.readyState;
        if (!callback.done && (!state || /loaded|complete/.test(state))) {
            callback.done = true;
            callback();
        }
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
}
```

And select list with languages (few examples):

```
<option value=108
        data-mime-type="text/x-csrc"
        data-script="/Scripts/codemirror-2.37/mode/clike/clike.js">
    C
</option>
<option value=110
        data-mime-type="text/x-csharp"
        data-script="/Scripts/codemirror-2.37/mode/clike/clike.js">
    C#
</option>
<option value=109
        data-mime-type="text/x-c++src"
        data-script="/Scripts/codemirror-2.37/mode/clike/clike.js">
    C++
</option>
```